# Xamarin Failed to resolve "System.Void Foundation.NSMutableDictionary

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Just updated to the latest Xamarin.iOS stable build and Xcode 7.1 on my Mac. When I build in Visual Studio for both simulator and device I get the following error:

Error 22 Failed to resolve "System.Void Foundation.NSMutableDictionary::set_Item(ObjCRuntime.INativeObject,ObjCRuntime.INativeObject)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"

[UPDATE]
When I set the Link behaviour to Don´t link the app launches on both simulator and device but crashes with the following error:

```
Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7d2c2e80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded) 2015-10-23 15:05:28.036 

 Error loading /System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib:  dlopen(/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib, 262): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin/Contents/MacOS/IOHIDLib: mach-o, but not built for iOS simulator

 Cannot find function pointer IOHIDLibFactory for factory 13AA9C44-6F1B-11D4-907C-0005028F18D5 in CFBundle/CFPlugIn 0x7d2c2e80 </System/Library/Extensions/IOHIDFamily.kext/Contents/PlugIns/IOHIDLib.plugin> (bundle, not loaded)
```

And I managed to narrow the problem to the camera which the app is using, down to the lines:

```
var dictionary = new NSMutableDictionary();
dictionary[AVVideo.CodecKey] = new NSNumber((int)AVVideoCodec.JPEG);
```

And the error is

```
[0:] Method 'NSMutableDictionary.set_Item' not found.
Attempting to JIT compile method ... while running with --aot-only. 
See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.
```

This used to work before I updated to XCode 7.1.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building for the simulator or a device? Also if you change `Don't link` in the `Link behavior` does it work then? Also do you have any other assemblies that you are including have not been re-compiled.

Comment: Hi @RobertN thanks for your quick reply. Please see the update, it seems the problem is related to the camera for some reason. However it used to work fine before I updated.

Comment: Take a look @ https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34621

Comment: I don´t have this EXEC folder in my ios project. Should I manually create it and copy all dll´s into it and reference them instead? It feels a bit dirty fix. Do you know why this error appears now but it has been working fine until I updated to the latest stable Xamarin code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using NSMutableDictionary which has been removed 
https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_9/xamarin.ios_9.0/#2